# Cannot convert value of type 'value' to expected argument type 'argument '

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I'm currently trying to convert my Swift iOS app to Swift 2. I've removed 99% of compiler errors but this one remains:

> Cannot convert value of type '(CMAltitudeData!, NSError!) -> Void' to
>   expected argument type 'CMAltitudeHandler' (aka
>   '(Optional, Optional) -> ()')

This is in response to this function:

```
func startAltimeterUpdate() {
    self.altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!,
        withHandler: { (altdata:CMAltitudeData!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            self.handleNewMeasure(pressureData: altdata)
    })
}
```

I am having a hard time understanding this error... what on earth is Xcode trying to tell me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to force an optional to become non-optional. Swift doesn't like that. Instead, try this:

```
func startAltimeterUpdate() {
    self.altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!,
        withHandler: { (altdata, error) -> Void in
            if let data = altdata {
                self.handleNewMeasure(pressureData: data)
            } else {
                // altdata is nil
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: no need to create another data constant. Use if let altdata = altdata or even better use guard let altdata = alt data where error == nil else { return }

Comment: Ahh okay, that makes a lot of sense. A lot of my other issues have been to do with the handling of optionals as well. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy.

<kbd>⌥</kbd>-click on `startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue` to get the documentation of the symbol.

You will see that the `CMAltitudeHandler` handler is declared as

```
CMAltitudeHandler = (CMAltitudeData?, NSError?) -> Void
```

Both parameters are optional `?` rather than implicit unwrapped optional `!`

That's what the error message says.